# How to use foreach and if statement within array of arrays?

Tags: php, plugin-development, array

I'm using [Tareq's WordPress Settings API](https://github.com/tareq1988/wordpress-settings-api-class) to develop a plugin with a settings page.

With the API, I am displaying checkbox items. However, I want to show additional checkboxes using the `foreach` and `if` statement.

- `foreach`: this will display additional checkboxes for every field in the [`wp_get_user_contact_methods()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_user_contact_methods/)
- `if`: this will display an extra set of checkboxes if another plugin is activated

This is what I have right now going off of my own logic:

```
$settings_fields = array( // Parent array
    'dsbl_basics' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'text_val',
            'label' => __( 'Text Input', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => 'Title',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'intval'
        )
    ),
    'dsbl_profile' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __( 'Name', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'first_name' => 'First Name',
                'last_name' => 'Last Name'
            )
        ),
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'contact_info',
            'label' => __( 'Contact Info', 'dsbl' ),
            'type' => 'multicheck',
            'options' => array(
                'url' => 'Website',
                foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $value => $label ) { // Additional contact fields
                    $value => $label
                }
            )
        ),
        if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) { // If plugin exists
            array( // Child's child array
                'name' => 'yoast_seo',
                'label' => __( 'Yoast SEO', 'dsbl' ),
                'type' => 'multicheck',
                'options' => array(
                    'wpseo_author_title' => 'Title to use for Author page',
                    'wpseo_author_metadesc' => 'Meta description to use for Author page'
                )
            ),
        }
    )
);
```

I know that my syntax is off which is giving me these errors:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `foreach` (T_FOREACH), expecting `)`
>
> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected `if` (T_IF), expecting `)`

What is the proper approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227230/6579923).

> You cannot put any loop or control structure `if/else` as `array` value or anywhere within `array()`.

#### Example

```
$contact_list = [];
$contact_list['url'] = 'Website';
foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $value => $label ) { 
    $contact_list[$value] = $label;
}
$settings_fields = array( // Parent array
    'dsbl_basics' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'text_val',
            'label' => 'Text Input'
        )
    ),
    'dsbl_profile' => array( // Child array
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'dsbl',
            'options' => array(
                'first_name' => 'First Name',
                'last_name' => 'Last Name'
            )
        ),
        array( // Child's child array
            'name' => 'contact_info',
            'label' => 'Contact Info', 
            'options' => $contact_list
        )
    )
);
$yoast_plugin = array( // Child's child array
    'name' => 'yoast_seo',
    'label' => 'Yoast SEO', 
    'options' => array(
        'wpseo_author_title' => 'Title to use for Author page',
        'wpseo_author_metadesc' => 'Meta description to use for Author page'
    )
);
if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) {
    $settings_fields['dsbl_profile'][1] = $yoast_plugin;
}
```